# Procedimientos almacenados CRUD en Oracle PL/SQL sin usar Cursores

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, crud

tengo una pequeña duda acerca de procedimientos almacenados en oracle, me pidieron realizar un CRUD de una tabla (Tabla: cargo ; Columnas: id, nombre y descripcion) usando Store Procedures, el problema es que para los SP me solicitaron que no use cursores. 
Mi duda es ¿Cómo hago para no usar Cursores?
Si alguien puede mostrarme un ejemplo por favor se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Es la columna ID una llave primaria o tal vez un índice único?

Comment: Si, la columna ID es la llave primaria de la tabla.